# System is exactly singular error when using pgmm (plm-package) in R

Tags: r, plm, economics, gmm

I am new to the *plm* package, but I need to do a system gmm on a dataset for my bachelor thesis in economics. I am trying to regress the GDP on the amount of railways stations built. This includes of course a lagged GDP variable and other controls, such as the human capital etc.

I use the pgmm function in the plm-package, however, I always get the following error message:

> Error in solve.default(crossprod(WX, t.CP.WX.A1)) :
>
> Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

I understand that this can occur if there is a high correlation between some variables, but I am quite sure that this is not the case.

This is the code I tried and a sample from the panel data:

```
gmm_estimator <- pgmm(log(GDP) ~ lag(log(GDP), 1:2) + lag(Stations, 0:1) + lag(Humancapital, 0:2)
                      | lag(log(GDP), 2:5),
                      data = Bachelor_DF,
                      effect = "twoways",
                      model="twosteps")

             id year       GDP  Stations Humancapital
GDP_1860    101 1870  370.5480         5           NA
GDP_1870    101 1880  430.2257         0   0.40458015
GDP_1880    101 1890  512.6674         0   0.31274131
GDP_1900    101 1900  657.8438         0   0.36095965
GDP_1910    101 1910  887.6366         0   0.48163265
GDP_1860.1  102 1870  383.6571         3           NA
GDP_1870.1  102 1880  431.9505         2   0.53590734
GDP_1880.1  102 1890  479.9470         0   0.30722892
GDP_1900.1  102 1900  659.2220         2   0.42857143
GDP_1910.1  102 1910  743.7952         0   0.49295775
GDP_1860.2  103 1870  327.8067         1           NA
GDP_1870.2  103 1880  411.4266         5   0.34935065
GDP_1880.2  103 1890  491.3625         0   0.23244552
GDP_1900.2  103 1900  727.0378         3   0.42086835
GDP_1910.2  103 1910  879.2722         1   0.44058745
GDP_1860.3  104 1870  364.6654         3           NA
GDP_1870.3  104 1880  456.8578         4   0.40669241
GDP_1880.3  104 1890  535.1647         0   0.23443223
GDP_1900.3  104 1900  767.6347         2   0.25925926
GDP_1910.3  104 1910  918.7938         0   0.41682975
GDP_1860.4  105 1870  358.7054         1           NA
GDP_1870.4  105 1880  461.3142         6   0.31396588
GDP_1880.4  105 1890  551.4780         2   0.28403361
GDP_1900.4  105 1900  764.8562         0   0.33770492
GDP_1910.4  105 1910 1081.6443         3   0.45477599
GDP_1860.5  106 1870  433.6760         0           NA
GDP_1870.5  106 1880  500.1974         3   0.40723982
GDP_1880.5  106 1890  582.9612         0   0.32718894
GDP_1900.5  106 1900  827.3129         2   0.38211788
GDP_1910.5  106 1910 1132.2033         0   0.51446945
GDP_1860.6  107 1870  439.5436         0           NA
GDP_1870.6  107 1880  520.0694         0   0.53041695
GDP_1880.6  107 1890  581.3917         0   0.37232143
GDP_1900.6  107 1900  767.7895         5   0.45877551
GDP_1910.6  107 1910  929.2661         0   0.57142857
GDP_1860.7  108 1870  391.5621         0           NA
GDP_1870.7  108 1880  446.5804         7   0.37020906
GDP_1880.7  108 1890  572.8922         0   0.29817833
GDP_1900.7  108 1900  771.3239         0   0.42473634
GDP_1910.7  108 1910 1065.9663         0   0.46185065
GDP_1860.8  109 1870  390.2888         3           NA
GDP_1870.8  109 1880  461.9698         0   0.44285714
GDP_1880.8  109 1890  567.3165         0   0.33956044
GDP_1900.8  109 1900  782.6338         0   0.39285714
GDP_1910.8  109 1910  944.6441         0   0.52597403
GDP_1860.9  110 1870  394.4520         3           NA
GDP_1870.9  110 1880  454.7100         8   0.51518560
GDP_1880.9  110 1890  638.3998         0   0.38557994
GDP_1900.9  110 1900  874.0908         0   0.42964286
GDP_1910.9  110 1910 1209.1216         4   0.54148282
```

I also experimented with using different lags as the instrument variable (unfortunately, I only have 5 different time periods for the GDP, so the time frame is quite limited in itself...).

Furthermore, I tried to change the effect to "individual", but the error persists.